# How to find JNDI name when creating entity classes from a database?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, jndi

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 to create a web app that can create, read, update, and delete from a database. I was following this tutorial (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html), but ran into an issue when I was creating the entity files. However, the window in which I am supposed to enter the data source to draw from requires a JNDI Name and Database Connection.

The connection is easy enough, since it's the name of the database I already have loaded through NetBeans. However, I have no idea what the JNDI name should be, and following the model name provided by the tutorial doesn't work. When I try that, or any other name, I get an error in the server log, which reads:

```
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : [" whatever name I entered"]
```

I found almost no information online regarding this problem or how to look up a JNDI name.

Comment: Have you added both the JDBC Resource and JDBC Connection pool in your glassfish? It sounds like you are either looking up to a wrong JNDI name or the JDBC resouce doesn't exist.

Comment: How would I go about looking at/adding to the glassfish? This is almost entirely new territory for me, but I am running Glassfish 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I opened the Glassfish admin console, and added a new JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Resource. There I was able to specify my JNDI name, and everything made sense after that.